# After entering start time and end time in a form when save a record, tree view record is disappearing in ODOO

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-7

After entering start time and end time in a form when save a record, tree view record is disappearing

Before saving form screenshot:

[image: Before saving form]

After saving form screenshot:

[image: After saving the form]

PYTHON CODE:

class daily_tree(osv.Model):
    _name = 'daily.tree'

```
_columns = {

    'start_time' : fields.datetime('Start Time'),
    'end_time' : fields.datetime('End Time'),
    'report' : fields.char('Summary ',),
    'daily_rsltts': fields.many2one('shift.form','Daily Id'),


}


  <group>
        <field name="daily_log">            
        <tree string="Logs" editable="bottom">

            <field name="start_time" />
            <field name="end_time" />
            <field name="report" />



        </tree>
        </field>
```

Comment: @DimaSan You have any idea to resolve this

Comment: no, but if you want to get an advice you should post some of your code, so than someone can help you.

Comment: I suspect that you have a domain filter that's preventing the records from showing....please post some code

Comment: I dont have any domain filter, same code working in local but not in testing.. please help

Comment: Any one got any solution? @AnandKulkarni